# Gulp cdnizer not working with relative link

Tags: gulp, gulp-cdnizer

I am writing a gulp task to replace the local links of libraries used in development to be replaced with public CDN links. This is the part of my index.html file.

```
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

Gulp task that I am writing is using [gulp-cdnizer](https://github.com/OverZealous/gulp-cdnizer)

```
gulp.task('cdn', function () {
  return gulp.src('.tmp/serve/index.html')
    .pipe(cdnizer([
            'google:angular',
            'cdnjs:jquery'
         ]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

It should generate following output

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script>if(!(window.jQuery)) cdnizerLoad("bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js");</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script><script>if(!(window.angular)) cdnizerLoad("bower_components/angular/angular.js");</script>
```

But it work's only when I remove the leading '../' from the links added in 
input HTML file

```
 <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

What changes do I need to make in gulp cdn task to achieve the desired result with previous HTML input.

**Edit**

Folder structure is like this.

[image: Project Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give details on your project layout so I'll assume it looks like this:

```
project/someOtherDirectory/gulpfile.js
project/someOtherDirectory/index.html
project/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js
project/bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

When you pass `'cdnjs:jquery'` to `gulp-cdnizer` it tries to find all paths in your `index.html` that match this [glob pattern](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer): `**/jquery?(-????????).?(min.)js`.

All file paths that match will be replaced with the corresponding paths pointing to [`//cdnjs.com`](http://cdnjs.com).

However the `**` glob pattern does not match directories that start with a `.` and since your paths all start with `../bower_components` that means none of them are replaced by `gulp-cdnizer`.

You need to make your paths absolute by providing the [`relativeRoot` option](https://github.com/OverZealous/cdnizer#optionsrelativeroot). You can do that by passing the [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) global.

You also need to provide the location of your `bower_components` folder using the [`bowerComponents` option](https://github.com/OverZealous/cdnizer#optionsbowercomponents):

```
gulp.task('cdn', function () {
  return gulp.src('/index.html')
    .pipe(cdnizer({
      relativeRoot: __dirname,
      bowerComponents: '../bower_components',
      files: [
        'google:angular',
        'cdnjs:jquery'
      ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I tried but could not actually get the output. Added folder structure for your reference.

Comment: If that's your project structure, then why does your code say `gulp.src('/index.html')` instead of `gulp.src('.tmp/serve/index.html')`? Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and go over your question again.

Comment: I wrote `gulp.src('/index.html')` to show it simple but in actual code I have used correct place. It worked what you suggested earlier. `relativeRoot: 'gulp/'` is the option I needed to add. My cdn task in inside `projectDir/gulp/cdn.js` Thanks again.